# Run TensorFlow op in graph mode in tf 2.x

Tags: tensorflow, benchmarking, tensorflow2.0

I would like to benchmark some TensorFlow operations (for example between them or against PyTorch). However most of the time I will write something like:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf_device = '/GPU:0'
a = np.random.normal(scale=100, size=shape).astype(np.int64)
b = np.array(7).astype(np.int64)

with tf.device(tf_device):
  a_tf = tf.constant(a)
  b_tf = tf.constant(b)

%timeit tf.math.floormod(a_tf, b_tf)
```

The problem with this approach is that it does the computation in eager-mode (I think in particular that it has to perform GPU to CPU placement). Eventually, I want to use those ops in a `tf.keras` model and therefore would like to evaluate their performance in graph mode.

What is the preferred way to do it?

My google searches have led to nothing and I don't know how to use sessions like in tf 1.x.

Comment: I think you're going to need to setup a graph and try it out. I don't get your question. Or even the problem you're having.

Comment: My question is: How would you go about doing the profiling I gave as an example in graph mode as opposed to eager execution mode?
How would you set up the graph?

Comment: You want to profile adding two numbers together? What would your graph be, an input with two numbers and the output those two numbers added together? That is such a ridiculously quick operation I would be impressed if you could measure it.

Comment: well no I want to profile some other operations (in this particular case the `tf.math.floormod` operation on large tensors but others too in the future).
As a matter of fact you can do the profiling I showed in the example and it gives me (on my machine) a time of `6.04 µs`, but I think it has to do with the fact that it's in eager mode.

Comment: You did not measure the time to add two numbers together. Maybe you should go through a keras tutorial and learn how to use it a bit. It would be pretty trivial to setup a graph that does such a simple operation. If that is your question, then maybe you should ask for that. It's still not clear what you're actually asking.

Comment: I don't understand. I don't necessarily want to use keras here, just know how I can profile/time a tensorflow operation in graph mode as opposed to eager execution.
I also don't want to profile specifically the `add` operation but rather any tf op.
If it's trivial do you mind sharing what you have in mind?

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean by "You did not measure the time to add two numbers together."?

Comment: It's trivial to setup a computational graph with tensorflow/keras that is what they're built for. I actually don't know what you want, so I could not set it up. It doesn't take a computer 6us to add two numbers together, you've measured overhead. I think you're trying to be abstract in your description, and you need to be a bit more specific. This example is too trivial.

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with `%timeit tf.add(a,b)` syntax, but that is a bit beside the point.

Comment: an example of what I would like to do in the end is: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ttYdhiIAk_MWpIMG7AnDCabAakn9aURe?usp=sharing

You can see that pytorch is way faster than TensorFlow but I think it might be in part imputable to TensorFlow running in eager mode. Do you know how to avoid that?

Comment: That is much better, because you're a & b are tensors and it would make sense to create  a computational graph. I think you should put that bit of code in the question. Maybe even include the pytorch bit that is compared to. Do you have a reason to believe eager execution would make a difference? The tf docs seem to suggest it shouldn't matter.

Comment: sure why not. Well it just seems very slow, and I know that for example when using models, training in eager mode vs training in graph mode makes a huge difference computation wise. I would assume this to be true in all settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `tf.function`. Check this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function) and this [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function).

As the tutorial says, in TensorFlow 2, eager execution is turned on by default. The user interface is intuitive and flexible (running one-off operations is much easier and faster), but this can come at the expense of performance and deployability. To get performant and portable models, use tf.function to make graphs out of your programs.

Check this code:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import timeit

tf_device = '/GPU:0'

shape = [100000]
a = np.random.normal(scale=100, size=shape).astype(np.int64)
b = np.array(7).astype(np.int64)

@tf.function
def experiment(a_tf, b_tf):
  tf.math.floormod(a_tf, b_tf)

with tf.device(tf_device):
  a_tf = tf.constant(a)
  b_tf = tf.constant(b)

# warm up
experiment(a_tf, b_tf)
print("In graph mode:", timeit.timeit(lambda: experiment(a_tf, b_tf), number=10))
print("In eager mode:", timeit.timeit(lambda: tf.math.floormod(a_tf, b_tf), number=10))
```